# How to remove everything after last hyphen using regex java

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove everything after last hyphen 
`branch:resource-fix-c95e12f`

I have tried with following command :

`replaceAll(".*[^/]*$","");`

I want the expected result as `branch:resource-fix`

Comment: Does expected solution *requires* regex? If so you can use `replaceAll("(.*)-[^-]*$","$1")`. `$x` in replacement part represents content of group x, here group 1: `(.*)`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `regex`, could you use

[`String::lastIndexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int))?

`str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf(‘-‘))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
-[^-]+$
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/dHSNNN/1

Comment: ***On side note:-*** this will not replace `hello-`, you may want to review the quantifier used

Comment: @CodeManiac, should it? I believe it is unclear, moreover, here we provide not a complete solution but a guidance, if OP needs, he/she can adjust the proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern

```
-[^-]*$
```

[image]

[`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/ASkGyP/2/)

Answer (score 1):

This expression might simply work:

```
-[^-]*$
```

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "-[^-]*$";
final String string = "branch:resource-fix-c95e12f";
final String subst = "";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println(result);
```

Another option would be, `^(.*)-.*$` replaced with `\\1`.

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/4KA0OD/1/)

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/J50I0q/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/J50I0q/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.